# Possible to Interface with Phone and Messaging?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I just got a windows phone(lumia 800) and been playing around with it. I still don't have a network to connect to so I can't really try the phone part out yet.

I am wondering though if I make an app can I

1. Make a phone call from my app? using the built in phone title I see?
2. Make a text(sms) message from my app using the messaging title I see?
3. When I am in say the messaging part it has a "to" line. It seems to be connected to the "people" part. Can I also connect that "to" line to my app in conjunction with the "people" title?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can using [PhoneCallTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
2. Same as the above, just use [SmsComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.smscomposetask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
3. Unfortunately, no. There is no way to expose third party contacts list to the built in application. You can, however, create similar functionality that will combine both phone contacts and your own.

You can query existing contacts using [Contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.userdata.contacts%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). On Windows Phone 8 you can add contacts using the [custom contacts store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207034%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), although I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Hmm so I basically would have to recreate the phone and sms tiles in my application to use my custom contact list. I planning to program for windows phone 7 still not 8.

Comment: Yes, you are pretty much limited on that for WP7.

Comment: limited by not being able querying contacts from the peoples tile?

Comment: You can query them and create a combined list of contacts from People Hub and yours, but only in your application. If user uses People Hub, it won't see your contacts. On WP8 you can add custom contacts to People Hub (check the link above), but you cannot do the same in WP7. That is why I've said that you are limited in WP7.

Comment: Ah ok. I am wondering with the SmsComposeTask park is there a project that you know off that made sort of the same gui that the Messaging tile has? Seems like alot of work to remake that gui and would be great if something already existed that I could use.

Comment: Ah found another page on it and I see you just pass the info to the built in messaging.